# node.js receiving POST data submitted through form using HTTP

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, post, https

I'm using a node.js server and need to post data over an http**s** protocol.

POST is listed as a http protocol, so I'm wondering if I'm on the wrong track.

Anyway, here is the *top* of my code that handles the POST. I've not included the on('end') function for berevity, but it is there.

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
if(req.method == 'POST'){
    var datastring = '';
    req.on('data', function(data){
        datastring += data;
        console.log("getting data");
        if(datastring.length > 1e6){
            req.connection.destroy();
        }
    });
```

Through console logs I can determine that the request is being made, and that the request is recognised as POST, but that req.on('data')'s function is never called.

I looked into a CONNECT protocol, but this isn't supported by browser forms - please advise how to send data through CONNECT if you don't think I can send POST data over HTTPS

Thanks for your help

EDIT: here is form that sends request:

```
<form name="loginForm" action="login" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()" class="separate-sections">
```

and here is node.js code that grabs post

```
var app= express();
...
app.post('/login', route_login.login);
```

To make a long story short, does POST work over HTTPS? It doesn't seem to be working here.

Comment: HTTPS isn’t really that kind of protocol. TLS/SSL are at a different level than HTTP. You shouldn’t need to worry about either. Have you called `req.end();`?

Comment: req.on('end') is there, I just haven't included it. It is never called, which is to be expected if he on('data') function is never called either

Comment: No, not `req.on("end")`. When you’re sending POST data, you have to end the request. Call `req.end()`.

Comment: I have nearly identical code that works fine

Comment: the only possibility I can think of is adding an `end` handler and . also having JUST this in the `data` handler: `datastring += data;` also, can you show us the code that SENDS the post request as well?

Comment: where exactly do I put req.end()?

Comment: i don't think you need req.end(), they read your question incorrectly. They thought that you were trying to use node.js to CREATE a post request while it seems that you are actually trying to recieve one.

Comment: so you've put in console.log into here and you HAVE been able to see that the request came to the server and the server was able to recognize it as a POST request? If you've gotten that far, then HTTPS cannot be the problem, I think.

Comment: That is what I mean to do, yes.

Comment: the request does come into the server and is handled fine, but seemingly no data is ever sent - it just waits for data from the post.

Comment: Just realized you would need to copy all chunks and parse the form data before you can get anything. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: I think I am doing that. req('on') data is adding the chunks to a datastring, and later on, when req('end') is called, I parse the data.
The problem is that I'm not getting any chunks at all.

Answer (score 0):

Found out someone on my team had added the express bodyparser, so naturally posts no longer work in the way I had before. The change just happened to coincide with when we switched to https which made it look as if this was the issue, when it was not.